# How to select text representation of AFP

Tags: sql, db2, mainframe

I am trying to select AFP records from a DB2 database. Normally, when I view the AFP on the mainframe, I can see a "text" representation of the AFP triplets:

```
..Lyy
.ñLÓÓ
..Ly®
..LyI
```

I have become pretty good at knowing what the triplets are based on which characters appear.

When I select from the database without casting it the EBCDIC CCSID, it returns the hex values:

```
5A0010D3A8
5A0049D3EE
5A0010D3A8
5A0008D3A8
```

**NOTE: These are the correct hex values for the triplets in question**

Is there anyway I can have my output from the database return the characters I am used to seeing when I browse the AFP on the mainframe? I have tried casting it to EBCDIC with the following SQL:

```
select CAST(column1 as varchar(10000) CCSID 37)
from tableA
where colunm2 = 123456789
```

but this is not showing the "correct" values:

```
!    
!    
!    
!
```

I can't think of another way to get these values to appear.

Comment: If you just need for casting the binary data to a readable string, this question does not deserve the [tag:afp] tag because it is not about the AFP. Otherwise, you may find the answer in [IBM reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_castspecification.html) for `CAST` clause

Comment: I can remove the AFP tag, but I was unable to find a clear answer in that IBM documentation. Maybe I am just reading it wrong.